# Замена символов в строке при переборе строки

Tags: javascript, циклы

Добрый день. В условии задачи есть строки:

```
var input = "javascript is awesome";
var output = "";
```

Нужно воспользоваться циклом for, чтобы перебрать все символы исходной строки. Встретив букву "а", заменить ее в результирующей строке на "4", "е" на "3", "i" на "1" и "о" на "0". В остальных случаях добавлять к результату исходный символ. Как это сделать? Задача в детском учебнике по JS, я понимаю как заменить символы без использования цикла, но как менять символы при перебере строки я вообще не понимаю.

Comment: обрати внимание на слова: _добавлять к результату_. У тебя есть пустая строка `output`. В цикле ты ей просто добавляешь в зависимости от условия нужный символ

Comment: Заменить не в строке, а в результате, т.е. добавить другой символ

Comment: Полагаю, эта задача хочет увидеть конструкцию switch

Comment: в цикле `for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++)` сделать обращение к символу строки `input[i]` и уже от ситуации сделать замену если нужно.

Answer (score 2):

Вот попроще вариант:

```
        var input = "javascript is awesome";
        var output = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){

            var outputSign = input[i];  

            if (outputSign == "a"){
                output += 4;
            } else if (outputSign == "e"){
                output += 3;
            } else if (outputSign == "i"){
                output += 1;                    
            } else if (outputSign == "o"){
                output += 0;
            } else {
            output += outputSign;
            };
        };
        document.write(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```js
var input = "javascript is awesome";
var output = "";
 
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, character) {
      return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
   }
 
for(var i = 0; i <= input.length; i++){ 
 if( input[i] == 'a' ){  
    input = input.replaceAt(i,"4"); 
 }
  else if( input[i] == 'e'){ 
    input = input.replaceAt(i,"3"); 
 }
   else if( input[i] == 'i'){ 
    input = input.replaceAt(i,"1"); 
 }
   else if( input[i] == 'o'){ 
    input = input.replaceAt(i,"0"); 
 }
}  
output = input;

console.log('javascript is awesome');
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "java script is awesome";
var output = " "; 
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
    if (input[i] === "a"){
        output += "4";
    } else if(input[i] === "e"){
        output += "3";
    } else if (input[i] === "i"){
        output += "1";
    } else if (input[i] === "o"){
        output += "0";
    } else {
        output += input[i];
    }
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: А чем ваше решение отличается от уже имеющихся? Уточните пожалуйста воспользовавшись [кнопкой править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1097514/edit).